# SQL Server Split one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to split one column of data into multiple (between 1 and 5 where necessary) based on the data in other columns being the same.
This is an example of my data after a query:

```
FirstName    LastName    StreetName    StreetNumber    AccountNumber
John         Smith       Fake St       123             10
John         Smith       Fake St       123             20
John         Smith       Fake St       123             30
John         Smith       Fake St       123             40
```

This is based on the fact that the same person at the same address can have multiple accounts, up to 5.  What I need my results to look like:

```
FirstName    LastName    StreetName    StreetNumber    AccountNumber1    AccountNumber2    AccountNumber3    AccountNumber4    AccountNumber5
John         Smith       Fake St       123             10                20                30                40                NULL
```

So I need the accountNumber column split into multiple columns based on the criteria that the name/address is the same.  I would like to just make 5 new columns and any empty field be a NULL value. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use simple pivot:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        'AccountNumber' + 
        cast(
          row_number()
          over(
              partition by [FirstName], [LastName], [StreetName], [StreetNumber]
              order by AccountNumber
          )
        as nvarchar(max)) as rn
    from Table1
)
select *
from cte
pivot (
    max(AccountNumber)
    for rn in (
        [AccountNumber1],
        [AccountNumber2],
        [AccountNumber3],
        [AccountNumber4],
        [AccountNumber5]
    )
) as p;
```

or you may pivot by hand:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        row_number()
        over(
            partition by [FirstName], [LastName], [StreetName], [StreetNumber]
            order by AccountNumber
        ) as rn
    from Table1
)
select
    [FirstName], [LastName], [StreetName], [StreetNumber],
    max(case when rn = 1 then AccountNumber end) as AccountNumber1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then AccountNumber end) as AccountNumber2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then AccountNumber end) as AccountNumber3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then AccountNumber end) as AccountNumber4,
    max(case when rn = 5 then AccountNumber end) as AccountNumber5
from cte
group by [FirstName], [LastName], [StreetName], [StreetNumber]
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5290/8)</kbd>**